# Python: why are there no stack frames for `warnings.warn`?

Tags: python, cpython, python-internals

Consider this code:

```
#!python3
import warnings
import sys

def my_showwarning(*args, **kwargs):
     frame = sys._getframe()
     while frame is not None:
         print('name:', frame.f_code.co_name, 'file:', frame.f_code.co_filename)
         frame = frame.f_back
warnings.showwarning = my_showwarning

def foo():
    bar()

def bar():
    warnings.warn('Not good', UserWarning)

warnings.resetwarnings()
warnings.simplefilter('always')
foo()
```

The output is:

```
name: my_showwarning file: /home/nikratio/tmp/test.py
name: bar file: /home/nikratio/tmp/test.py
name: foo file: /home/nikratio/tmp/test.py
name: <module> file: /home/nikratio/tmp/test.py
```

Why are there no stack frames between `bar()` and `my_showwarnings`? Looking at the implementation in CPython 3.4.4, `warnings.warn` should call `warnings.warn_explicit`, which finally calls `showwarning` - so it seems to me that there should be (at least) two more stackframes.

Is that related to the fact that CPython seems to use the C version (`_warnings`) by default? Do C extension functions not have any stack frames at all?

Comment: C extensions use the C stack (unless you explicitly write code to emulate a Python frame, which is something that nobody does)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: In my experience, [Cython](http://cython.org) typically does bother with that, mostly because otherwise the errors would be entirely incomprehensible.

Comment: @Kevin: indeed. But Cython does that for free, you don't have to write any line of code for that